# Scraping ecomm website for products info listed on one single page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape flipkart.com (I randomly opened a category that displayed 60 products).

However using `BeautifulSoup` when I searched for all the links , I didn't get the links pointing to each product. I obtained 37 links none of which pointed towards the product description page....HELP!!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# a random product listing page 
url='https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile&sid=tyy/4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=start&as-pos=1_1_ic_mobile'       

r=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,from_encoding="utf-8")
links=soup.find_all('a')
```

It gave all the links except the links `toproduct descrtiption` page .

Comment: `data-reactid` in the first url returned gives you a good clue as to why

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (warning, I'm a noob): When you open the page in question with a normal browser, there is javascript in the page that when processed creates additional html that your browser adds to the document it shows you. When you use the requests module to get the page html it does not process this javascript so it never gets this extra content. The info you want is contained in this missing content. So:

Based on code from this thread: [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile&sid=tyy/4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=start&as-pos=1_1_ic_mobile'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col col-7-12'})
target_links = [link.parent.parent.parent for link in links]
for link in target_links:
    try:
        print(link.find('a')['href'])
    except TypeError:  # we caught unwanted links in the find_all
        pass
```

I'm sure the way I steered to the links could be improved.